# How do I get 5 haystack kills?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In the last part of the first DNA section, you're in a small village searching for the Templar leader. The optional objective for this section is to kill 5 enemies from haystacks.

There are a couple haystacks along the path to the final fight, but I wasn't able to get 5 kills from them. There are also haystacks in the final area, but I ended up low on health and surrounded by so many guards that I had to frantically kite and kill them without getting to use the haystacks.

Is it possible to get the 5 haystack kills on the path to the Templar leader, or do you have to get some haystack kills in the final battle of the section?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There aren't very many haystacks in the level where templars have patrol routes that go by them.  I count 4 total, 3 near patrol routes.

- When you first enter the town (only 1 templar patrols by)
- After you reach the market where there's a lot of civilians (only 1 templar patrols by)
- In the corner to your right after you reach the stronghold and you are locked in (only 1 templar patrols by)
- In front of the tower behind the stationed guards (none patrols by)

You need to lure some to the haystacks in order to get the required kills.

An easy way to do it would be to go to the first one, get the one that is on patrol first.  With him out of the way, go in to **High Profile** in front of the stationed guards (far away but close enough for them to notice you) until they are in the yellow.  They'll start walking toward you.  Make your way to the haystack and get ready for the kill (you may need to wait for them so they see you going toward the haystack).  Repeat as needed.

It's possible to do it in the other haystacks as well but most won't be as easy as the first.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to lure the guards near the first haystack and completed the full synchronization by doing that. I killed the first guard after the windmill with a normal assassination followed by hiding in the haystack for the second guard to walk-by, and assassinated him from the haystack. After that was all done, 2 guards starting approaching and I was able to assassinate 1 from haystack then quickly ran around until the other was off me, got his attention again and lured him to me in the haystack so that was 3 out of 5 done. Once those were completed, I went over to the 2 other guards that were sitting in that little doorway area not far from the haystack and carriage (they were just standing there) and lured each one individually to the haystack to complete 5 out of 5 for the full synch (Kill at least 5 guards from a haystack)... So I don't know if that would work for everyone else, maybe I just got lucky but I at least figured I would explain to anyone else looking this up. AC: Revelations was my least favorite AC game within the releases for the Xbox 360 console only and never beat it so I'm going back and beating it for the first time. Trying to get 100% game completion do to myself being an achievement hunter lol.. It was bothering me that I never played and beat it (AC: Revelations) and I loved playing Ezio in ACII & AC:Brotherhood, so here I am lol (2021)